# How many virtual tables will be there if a class has public, private and protected virtual functions?

Tags: c++, oop

I read that in C++, the compiler setups a virtual table for the class if it has at least one virtual function. The compiler also adds a hidden pointer for each object instantiation that points to the virtual table for that class.

Consider the following class:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    virtual int functionA(void) { return 0; }

private:
    virtual int functionB(void) { return 1; }

protected:
    virtual int functionC(void) { return 2; }
};
```

Will an object of this class have a single pointer to a virtual table or three different pointers to virtual tables for each access specifier?

Comment: As you had read, the compiler will set up a virtual table, and each instance of the class that object will have a hidden pointer that points to that virtual table.  For the code example, it will have a single table, and each instance a single pointer to that table.  (This arrangement is not specified in the C++ standard, it's merely a very common implementation detail.  There may be some platforms that use other trickery.)

Comment: Note that virtual functions are usually used in conjunction with derived classes, and there's no way to tell whether there will be overrides, nor what the access specifier of those overrides would be. Yet the compiler needs to know where to find each virtual function in a vtable.

Answer (score 3):

It's very important to understand, first of all, that there's no mention of "virtual tables" in the C++ standard. The C++ standard specifies the ***results*** and the ***expected behavior*** of a C++ program.

"Virtual tables" are just an implementation detail that results in the expected behavior of a C++ program. A C++ implementation is free to implement virtual class methods in some way that does not employ the services of "virtual tables", as long as the results are what's specified by the C++ standard. Having said all of that:

The typical implementation of virtual inheritance in modern C++ compilers always employs a single virtual table. Whether an individual class method (virtual or not) is private, protected, or public: this is ***access control***. Access control is checked at ***compile time***. Provided that the C++ program does not access private/protected class members in a manner that makes the resulting code ill-formed, and results in the compilation error: your end results are classes and objects with virtual functions; and at runtime all virtual functions are alike, and only need a single virtual table to dispatch them.

As a P.S.: with link-time optimization techniques in modern C++ compilers, I would not be surprised to learn that my C++ compiler figured out that in my C++ program a virtual class method never actually ends up getting overridden, and if true for all class members no virtual table gets created as a result.

Comment: So is there a single virtual table for all objects or one table per object?

Comment: There is one table per most derived class. You can create a trillion objects, of the same class. All of them will refer to the same virtual table. Why would they need to have their own table, when all their virtual methods are the same?